# Phonegap/Android - Notification's sound and vibration does not play during a phone call

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

On an Android device, during a phone call, the notification sound does not play nor the vibration to let the user know about it.

#### Expected Behavior

Play the notification sound and the vibration pattern even if the user is having a phone call.

#### Reproduce Scenario (including but not limited to)

Using a smartphone start a phone call and push the notification, you'll see that you'll not hear the notification voice nor feel the vibration.

***P.S. The vibration never trigger in all the cases.***

Steps to Reproduce

```
    1.  Start a phone call
    2. Push the notification, using the sample code that can be found below.
```

Platform and Version (eg. Android 5.0 or iOS 9.2.1)

## Android  6.0

(Android) What device vendor (e.g. Samsung, HTC, Sony...)

**Samsung Note 5**

Cordova CLI version and cordova platform version

```
cordova --version              
 6.3.0
cordova platform version android   
android 5.2.2
```

Plugin version

phonegap-plugin-push 1.8.0 "PushPlugin"

Sample Push Data Payload

N/A

Sample Code that illustrates the problem

```
             data: {
                   sound: "default",
                   title: "New",
                   alert: "This is a new notification !",
                   soundname:"ringtone",
                   vibrate:true,
                   vibrationPattern: [2000, 1000, 500, 500],
                   priority: 2,
                   visibility: 1
               }
```

Logs taken while reproducing problem

N/A

Answer (score 0):

I think you can fix this but on the android phone solely, specifically its native settings. Try the following steps.

Here are the steps to configure the push notification sound setting during a Phone call (Android):

**1.** Go to dialer
**2.** Click on the "More" at the top right
**3.** Select Settings
**4.** Click Call Alerts and change Notify during calls setting.